# SOLR 6.2 ignores heap settings (SOLR_JAVA_MEM param)

Tags: java, ubuntu, solr, amazon-ec2, sunspot

I've followed instructions from [here](http://www.andrewrowland.com/article/display/install-solr-5-and-zookeeper-in-a-production-environment/) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/JVM+Settings) to increase my SOLR memory allocation. I've done this because the SOLR server has shutdown periodically during some high frequency and high volume indexing activity.

I'm a little new to using SOLR and Ubuntu so bear with me, but I've found several locations where the SOLR_JAV_MEM parameter exist:

```
/opt/solr-6.2.0/bin/solr.in.sh
/opt/solr-6.2.0/bin/solr.in.cmd
/opt/solr-6.2.0/bin/solr.cmd
The same set of files in this directory: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.5/solr/bin
And this directory: 
/home/deploy/solr-6.2.0/bin 
And finally, in this file: /etc/default/solr.in.sh
```

Anywhere I've seen a SOLR_JAV_MEM or SOLR_HEAP param with a number, I've replaced it with a larger value, for example in /opt/solr-6.2.0/bin/solr.in.sh:

```
# Increase Java Heap as needed to support your indexing / query needs
SOLR_HEAP="1500m"

# Expert: If you want finer control over memory options, specify them directly
# Comment out SOLR_HEAP if you are using this though, that takes precedence
#SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms1512m -Xmx1512m"
```

If I'm measuring it correctly, I still only see about 500MB of memory allocated to SOLR, as seen by the following command:

```
root@ip-xxx:~# service solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes:

Solr process 15259 running on port 8989
{
  "solr_home":"/var/solr/data",
  "version":"6.2.0 764d0f19151dbff6f5fcd9fc4b2682cf934590c5 - mike - 2016-08-20 05:41:37",
  "startTime":"2016-09-28T15:01:18.001Z",
  "uptime":"0 days, 0 hours, 12 minutes, 28 seconds",
  "memory":"100 MB (%20.4) of 490.7 MB"}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I just measuring the memory incorrectly? Please let me know if I can provide add'l info. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'll answer my own question. It turned out that I had to edit the /etc/default/solr.in.sh file. I changed the SOLR_HEAP="512M" to SOLR_HEAP="1500m" and ran `sudo service solr status` and saw the memory showing 1.5G!

Comment: Thank you, your answer pointed me in the right direction. After I ran `sudo find -name solr.in.sh` on my server It came up in the Gemfile solr.in.sh file and I was able to set the mem size properly.

Comment: you can also accept your own answer, to make it more visible that your question is solved.